# Expanding english contractions using regular expressions in python

Tags: python, regex, nlp

I am trying to expand the English contractions like won't, 
i'll etc.
I have kept all the contractions with their abbreviations in the dictionary form inside a file.
ex:

```
CONTRACTION_MAP ={"ain't": "is not","aren't": "are not","can't": "cannot","can't've": "cannot have","'cause": "because","could've": "could have","couldn't": "could not","couldn't've": "could not have"..........etc}
```

Below is the code to expand the contractions

```
from contractions import CONTRACTION_MAP
import re
    def expand_contractions(sentence,contraction_map):
        contractions_pattern = re.compile('({})'.format('|'.join(contraction_map.keys())),flags=re.IGNORECASE|re.DOTALL)
        def expand_match(contraction):
             match=contraction.group(0)
             expanded_contraction = contraction_map.get(match)
             return expanded_contraction
        expanded_sentence = contractions_pattern.sub(expand_match,sentence)
        return expanded_sentence
```

My question is if I use can't've in my text, the can't've word is expanded as cannot've instead of cannot have.

```
sentence = "Paul can't've ice cream as he is suffering with cough"
print(expand_contractions(sentence,CONTRACTION_MAP))
output = > Paul cannot've ice cream as he is suffering with cough
```

Can anyone help me in figuring out what changes need to be done in the code to get the expected output.

Comment: Can you add to the map at the end `"n't" : " not", "'ve" : " have"`?

Comment: You need to order the text you are matching by length, match the longest first. This will find `can't've`  before `can't`.